# How to break code in modules in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm with the following code that needs to be used in two files:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InfoSchema = new Schema ({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});

var Info = mongoose.model('Info', InfoSchema);
```

I need use the Info variable in my listTerminal.js, and i need use the InfoSchema in my routes.js .

I'm new in Node.js, and still confuse me a lot the module.exports. Can anyone give me a light?

I was trying to do like this:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var InfoSchema = new Schema ({
        name: String,
        email: String,
    });
};
```

Them call in my routes.js and listTerminal.js like this:

```
var mySchema = require('../config/mongo/mySchema');
```

But is not working, cause in my route.js, i have a route like this:

```
app.post('/person', function(req, res) {
    var Data = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    };

    var info = new Info(Data);

    info.save(function (error, data){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```

And the page shows:

```
Info is not defined
```

How can i call this mySchema.js in another file??

OBS: if i move the myschema.js code to my route.js file, the route.js will work, but i need separate ;[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module should look like this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InfoSchema = new Schema ({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Info', InfoSchema);
```

That way you're exporting the model, not the schema. Then you can use it like so:

```
var Info = require('../config/mongo/mySchema');

app.post('/person', function(req, res) {
    var Data = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    };

    var info = new Info(Data);

    info.save(function (error, data){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var mySchema = require('../config/mongo/mySchema');
```

then `mySchema` **becomes** what `module.exports` is. Since it is a function (in your case) then you have to simply call it:

```
mySchema();
```

BTW: I don't know why you defined it as a function. Might not be the best idea.

Comment: how can i improve that @freakish??